# Issue in adcash api curl code

Tags: php, curl

All,

I have written a curl to get the details from Adcash API. Output of this API is to get the token number after login.

Below code is working good but it is not getting the token as output. It is null. Any suggestions.

```
   <?php
      try{
      Echo "Executing started";
      $url = "https://www.adcash.com/console/login_proxy.php";
       $ch = curl_init();

      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,  "userid:password");

      $output = curl_exec($ch);
      $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
      var_dump($info) ;
      echo $output;

      if (FALSE === $output)
        throw new Exception(curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));
        Echo "Executing Completed";
       curl_close($ch);
      } catch(Exception $e) {

          trigger_error(sprintf(
              'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
              $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
              E_USER_ERROR);

      }
    ?>
```

I have updated the code to get the subid report. please check and let me know what is the issue.

```
<?php
try{
Echo "Executing started";
$url = "https://www.adcash.com/console/login_proxy.php";
$ch = curl_init();

$logindata = array (
        'login' => 'xxx',
        'password' => 'xxx'
);
$logindata1 = http_build_query($logindata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $logindata1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$json_a=json_decode($output,true);
$token= $json_a["token"];

curl_close($ch);
$url = "https://www.adcash.com/console/login_proxy.php";
$ch = curl_init();
$logindata1 = http_build_query($logindata);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $logindata1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "token=". $token  . "&call=get_publisher_detailed_statistics");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
var_dump($output);

curl_close($ch);
} catch(Exception $e) {

    trigger_error(sprintf(
        'Curl failed with error #%d: %s',
        $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage()),
        E_USER_ERROR);

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm part of Adcash IT team. First of all, thanks for using our API. The problem in your code is that you're using HTTP authentication. Our API is using POST.

This part of your code:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,  "userid:password");
```

Can be replaced by:

```
$logindata = array (
'login' => YOUR_LOGIN_HERE,
'password' => YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE
);

$logindata = http_build_query($logindata);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.adcash.com/console/login_proxy.php');
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Could you please post the full code to get the subid report from adcash. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: The above works to get the token. But how to use the token to get the subid report?

Comment: I have updated the code to get subid report. please check and let me know how to proceed on this.

Comment: Any luck on this? . Still looking for answers